# Configure the position of DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Please help me to configure my Dialog Fragment, I want it to be in center on screen but making Gravity.CENTER didnt help.

Here is a code that i working with:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP);
WindowManager.LayoutParams param = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
param.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
param.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE;
param.x = 100;
param.y = 100;

getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(p);
```

But as u see on image this isnt look good
[image]

My queastion is how to take this to center and also move slighty to bottom
Any help approciate

Edit: This is my layout file with all items on the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="FEEDBACK &amp; CONTACT"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Text.Medium"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Got some ideas? Need some help?\n Send us a note!"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:hint="Type a message here"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinnerContactAndFeedback"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Help us improve Spontime! We will appreciate\n your rate and review!"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rateButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/green_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="RATE"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/send_mail_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
        android:scaleX="@dimen/login_min_scale"
        android:scaleY="@dimen/login_min_scale">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_send"
            style="@style/CurvedView.Login.Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_btn_height"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerContactAndFeedback"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your dialog is almost full screen. You can consider changing the position of the "send" button first. After that gravity center will work fine.

Comment: add your layout file.

Comment: I uploaded layout file

Answer (score -1):

Add the following attribute to your RelativeLayout

```
android:gravity="center"
```